# Word/phrase for getting people to do something because people in that bucket/group exhibit positive behaviours

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Scenario: We are a supermarket that has a rewards card program and customers using this program exhibit positive behaviours (e.g. increased spending at our stores). It is assumed this is beacuse they are more engaged in the brand.

We want to increase spending for non-rewards customers (they generally spend less), therefore it has been suggested that we force everyone to get a rewards card in the hopes it will increase their spending too.

However these customers aren't as engaged in the brand, therefore their spending may not increase as expected.

To summarise, is there a word or phrase for the following sort of logic/process of thinking?

> Trying to get people into a certain bucket/group because that bucket/group exhibits desired behaviours and expecting them to behave the same, even though they are different types of people.
>
> This is of course doomed to fail as these are different types of customers and aren't going to suddenly change their behaviour.

A possible usage sentence may be (it's hard for me to guess since I don't know the word/phrase)

> Although getting more people to use our rewards card to increase spending sounds like it would work, I think your idea falls victim to the following_____________.

Comment: Make the customer join the brand aware group

Comment: It's not clear (to me) quite what you're asking about.  Are you asking about trying to get people into the group, or the fact that it seems doomed to fail because you expect them to suddenly start acting like different people?  An example sentence (containing a blank for the "missing" word) would help a great deal.

Comment: You mean customers who are coerced into owning a reward card do not normally become faithful customers. Well, duh! :) There are many reasons why shoppers pick a favourite store and stick with that one, having someone shove their loyalty card in your face is not one of them :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am meaning, it's doomed to fail of course. However what would you call this sort of flawed logic? I have edited the end of the question to make it clearer hopefully.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'bucket'. What dialect of English do you speak or is that from?

Comment: If you want to notify users you must place @ plus their username. Because you are the author, you will receive a notification anytime a comment is written underneath.  I think you must be looking for something similar to **counter productive**, loyal customers who have their rewards card buy more, ergo new customers with cards will buy more. It's a flawed logic. [*Fallacy argument*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_fallacy)... etc.

Comment: You should provide a sample sentence with a _____ where the word or expression would fit. And tag your question `single-word-requests` and `phrase-request` There are users who pounce on those tags :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you are on the right track with the fallacy argument. I have updated the question with a possible example sentence.

Comment: @Clare I live in Australia, bucket is a term used by data analysts here for a group of similar people, or data points etc.

Comment: @JaydenMeyer awesome, love it. I'll give it a try in Virginia  USA

Comment: Getting off topic, but “it's doomed to fail” is an understatement.  If a business that I patronized ***required*** me to get a rewards card, I would start shopping elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There's an adage that covers the whole scenario:

> You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink.

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-can-lead-a-horse-to-water-but-you-can-t-make-him-drink) explains:

> *saying* ​ used to emphasize that you can make it easy for someone to do
>   [/ encourage them to do] something, but you cannot force them to do it

Answer (score 0):

The word would be 'compel'.  You want to 'compel' people to join your group by offering 'compelling' rewards.

Compel:
To have a powerful and irresistible effect, influence, etc.

Compel can have undertones of using force, but in regards to a rewards program they are not being *forced* to join they should probably feel influenced, rather than forced.